# PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.xxx - is this a typo?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, anaconda3, pytest-markers

I have a file called test.py with the following code:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.webtest
def test_http_request():
    pass

class TestClass:
    def test_method(self):
        pass
```

pytest -s test.py passed but gave the following warnings:

```
pytest -s test.py
=============================== test session starts ============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-5.2.4, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/user
collected 2 items

test.py ..

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/mark/structures.py:325
  ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/mark/structures.py:325:
    PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.webtest - is this a typo?  You can register
    custom marks to avoid this warning - for details, see https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/mark.html
    PytestUnknownMarkWarning,

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
=============================== 2 passed, 1 warnings in 0.03s ===================
```

Environment: Python 3.7.3, pytest 5.2.4, anaconda3

What is the best way to get rid of the warning message?

Answer (score 57):

To properly handle this you need to [`register the custom marker`](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#registering-markers). Create a `pytest.ini` file and place the following inside of it.

```
[pytest]
markers =
    webtest: mark a test as a webtest.
```

Next time you run the tests, the warning about the unregistered marker will not be there.

Comment: Yes, plus if a project has `pytest.ini` no other registration methods will works.

Answer (score 8):

without updating pytest.ini, we can ignore warning using --disable-warnings

We can also use --disable-pytest-warnings

Example using your case:
pytest -s test.py -m webtest --disable-warnings

Answer (score 4):

To add to the existing answers - custom markers can also be registered in `pyproject.toml`:

```
# pyproject.toml

[tool.pytest.ini_options]
markers = [
    "webtest: mark a test as a webtest.",
]
```

[Related docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/mark.html#registering-marks).

Answer (score 3):

@gold_cy's answer works. If you have too many custom markers need to register in pytest.ini, an alternative way is to use the following configuration in pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::UserWarning
```

or in general, use the following:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    error
    ignore::UserWarning
```

the configuration above will ignore all user warnings, but will transform all other warnings into errors. See more at [Warnings Capture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html)

test.py (updated with two custom markers)

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.webtest
def test_http_request():
    print("webtest::test_http_request() called")

class TestClass:
    @pytest.mark.test1
    def test_method(self):
        print("test1::test_method() called")
```

Use the following commands to run desired tests:

```
pytest -s test.py -m webtest
pytest -s test.py -m test1
```

Comment: this is the _incorrect_ approach because this will ignore _all_ `UserWarnings`, even valid ones coming from other 3rd party libraries. the proper way is to register your custom markers, regardless of how many you have.

Comment: I agree, but can't figure out how to just suppress this particular warning. Tried setting it to:
`filterwarnings = ignore::PytestUnknownMarkWarning`. But it failed with this: `warnings._OptionError: unknown warning category: 'PytestUnknownMarkWarning'`.

Comment: @Jonathan L What is the difference between the 2 declarations you mentioned in your answer? Is one recommended over the other?

Comment: @philomath there is no preference for the two configurations. You can pick the one that fit your project need

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get rid of the message is to register the custom marker as per @gold_cy's answer.

However if you just wish to suppress the warning as per Jonathon's answer, rather than ignoring `UserWarning` (which will suppress *all* instances of the warning regardless of their source) you can specify the particular warning you want to suppress like so (in `pytest.ini`):

`ignore::_pytest.warning_types.PytestUnknownMarkWarning`

Note: For third party libraries/modules the full path to the warning is required to avoid an `_OptionError` exception

Answer (score 2):

Another more complete and up-to-date (pytest 7.4.0 at the time of writing) answer also incorporating other [configuration file formats](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/reference/customize.html#configuration-file-formats) such as pyproject.toml, e.g., for poetry users. The answer is based on [pytest docs on registering marks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/how-to/mark.html#registering-marks) and the [pytest example on custom markers](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/example/markers.html#registering-markers):

## Registering markers

### Possibility 1: pytest.ini

You can define a marker with explanation (`webtest`) and without (`other`) in pytest.ini:

```ini
[pytest]
markers =
    webtest: mark a test as a webtest
    
    other
```

### Possibility 2: pyproject.toml

If you're already using a [PEP-518](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/) build system (e.g., poetry) with pyproject.toml, you can also specify pytest options there instead of adding an additional pytest.ini. The pyproject.toml file format is slightly different:

```ini
[tools.pytest.ini_options]
markers = [
    "webtest: mark a test as a webtest",
    "other",
]
```

### Possibility 3: conftest.py

Another option is to register the markers in conftest.py, e.g., next to your marker's code. This is [recommended for pytest plugin authors](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/how-to/writing_plugins.html#registering-markers).

```py
def pytest_configure(config):
    config.addinivalue_line("markers", "webtest: mark a test as a webtest")
    config.addinivalue_line("other")
```

### Markers with arguments

Either way, you can register [markers with arguments](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/example/markers.html#custom-marker-and-command-line-option-to-control-test-runs) using `mymarker(myarg): a marker receiving one argument`.

## Checking successful registration with pytest

Either, run all your tests and check for any `PytestUnknownMarkWarning`s in the output or run `pytest --strict-markers` to run tests and fail on unknown markers.

Alternatively, run `pytest --markers` which will only output available markers without running the tests. Successfully registered markers should be contained in the `pytest --markers` output. Markers registered in conftest.py will only be shown in the output if you're launching pytest in the directory containing this conftest.py - but they will work, i.e., fix the PytestUnknownMarkWarning, in nested directories, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have `pytest.ini` and don't wanna create one just for this then you can also register it programmatically in `conftest.py` as described [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/markers.html#custom-marker-and-command-line-option-to-control-test-runs):

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    # register an additional marker
    config.addinivalue_line(
        "markers", "env(name): mark test to run only on named environment"
    )
```